# pagebulider error on backed

Tags: error, magento2.4, backend, static-block, page-builder

Working on magento 2.4.4 instance.I created a block from backend and call that block in the homepage with help of pagebuilder.After saving the page,

```
Error filtering template:Invalid block type:Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons\InCatalog
```

but its working fine on frontend without any issue.
Can anybody suggest me to fix this error on backend.

here is the image
[image: error screen]

Thanks in Advance.